# How to know whether Send/Discard/Cancel button pressed in Email Compose Activity - Android

Tags: android

I have launched email compose `Activity` by using `Intent.ACTION_SEND`.

Can someone please tell me how I can get the confirmation/callback when user Send, Discard or  Cancel email?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no standardized intent returned by email apps in response to ACTION_SEND. The best way to do it would be to provide the form for creating the email yourself, and only send the intent off if the user chooses to actually send it.